# [ros2] Including a launch file in a launch file with parameter overrides

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two launch files `A.launch.py` and `B.launch.py`. The `B` launch file has a set of parameters with default values. I want to include the `B` launch file in `A` so that launching `A` also launches `B`.

So far this works fine and I have no problems.

However, now I want to specify some parameter values in `A` that override the default values specified in `B`. How do I do this? It was pretty straightforward to do this in ROS 1 with the XML syntax, but I can't find any straightforward way to do in ROS 2 with the python launch file syntax.

My question is basically this one, but for ROS 2: #q62949.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369840/%5Bros2%5D-including-a-launch-file-in-a-launch-file-with-parameter-overrides/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2021-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I've answered my own question. I got it to work by adding a `launch_arguments` argument to the `IncludeLaunchDescription` command:

Before:

```
ld = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        os.path.join(pkg_prefix, 'B.launch.py')))
```

After:

```
ld = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        os.path.join(pkg_prefix, 'B.launch.py')),
    launch_arguments={
        'parameter_name1': 'parameter_value1',
        'parameter_name2': 'parameter_value2'
    }.items()
)
```

Note that both parameter name and value are strings. The value can also be a `launch.Substitution`, but I don't know how those work. The string value works for my purposes.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on 2021-09-29**:
how do you then parse the launch arguments in `B.launch.py`

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2021-10-04**:
Instead of calling them 'parameters', it would be better to call them launch file arguments. What I imagine the questioner is doing in B.launch.py is declaring some launch file arguments which are then being used to set parameters. So to answer your question @morten, you would just declare a launch file argument in B.launch.py.